# Connection String to MySQL Temporary Table in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a temporary table in memory in order to store some data in it and use it within the application life time..

I am trying to do something as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE XmlItems ENGINE=MEMORY AS (");
// Continue with columns definitions
sb.append(")");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
```

But the following exception is being thrown:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I'm guessing it has to do something with the connection string..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided schema name in the jdbc connection URL. Try after adding schema name at the end of URL.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the database in this case mysql is started/running, the connection `String` look fine despite the fact the you've not added the database name to be used instead of `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"` use `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databae_name"`

Answer (score 0):

The connection string has to contain a database schema to connect to.

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myTestDB");`

Also, make sure that MySQL is actually running. "Communications link failure" sounds more like the connection to port 3306 is refused.